# Use Generics <K> to reduce duplicate code?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I have below code. As you can see I am executing similar logic but once for Bike and once for Car. Can I make use for `<K>` to reduce duplicate looking code? I have not used `<K>` so I am not sure where and how exactly I can incorporate it. Where can I make the decision whether to call `getCarsWithFeature` or `getBikesWithFeature`?

Is it best practice to reduce number of lines (may make it less readable) or to have such duplicate-looking code?

```
public Set<Car> getPremiumCars(String filter) {
    final Callable<Set<Car>> retryGetCars = new RetryingCallable<>(retryStrategy(), getCars(filter));  
    return retryGetCars.call();
}

public Callable<Set<Car>> getCars(String feature) {
    return new Callable<Set<Car>>() {
        @Override
        public Set<Car> call() throws Exception {
            Set<Car> cars = getCarsWithFeature(feature); 
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(cars);
        }
    };
}

public Set<Bike> getPremiumBikes(String filter) {
    final Callable<Set<Bike>> retryGetBikes = new RetryingCallable<>(retryStrategy(), getBikes(filter));
    return retryGetBikes.call();            
}

public Callable<Set<Bike>> getBikes(String feature) {
    return new Callable<Set<Bike>>() {
        @Override
        public Set<Bike> call() throws Exception {
            Set<Bike> bikes = getBikesWithFeature(feature); 
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(bikes);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can if you have a common (base class) type for both Car and a Bike

Comment: You might be able to but of Cars and Bikes are at all different I think you'll run into trouble with generics.  It might be better to factor all common code into an abstract base class, since that will still allow you to specialize any code need for a Bike or Car subclass.

Comment: Answer to this question should cope with `getCarsWithFeature` and `getBikesWithFeature`. Using generics or not they seem to be different calls that have to be made.

Comment: Thanks @Piro. Yes they are indeed different calls. Is using generics not possible in this case?

Comment: Why is the code peppered with `Callables` and other unrelated things? Since you're having trouble with the basics, you should stick to basic code instead of trying to make it look "advanced" for no reason.

Comment: @kayaman Sorry if it is misleading but the actual code is much more complicated than this. I tried to simplify as much as I could. I have not used Generics extensively and hence have some trouble in that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know your whole code, but I would suggest for both classes to implement same interface - let's say `Vehicle`:

```
  public interface Vehicle {
  }
```

Then you could write code that lately you can reuse:

```
  public <T extends Vehicle> Set<T> getPremiumVehicle(Function<String, Callable<Set<T>>> vehicleSupplier, String filter) throws Exception {
    final Callable<Set<T>> retryGetCars = new RetryingCallable<T>(retryStrategy(), vehicleSupplier.apply(filter));
    return retryGetCars.call();
  }

  public <T extends Vehicle> Callable<Set<T>> getVehicle(Function<String, Set<T>> vehicleSupplier, String feature) {
    return () -> {
      Set<T> vehicles = vehicleSupplier.apply(feature);
      return Collections.unmodifiableSet(vehicles);
    };
  }
```

Now, you could reuse above code, like:

```
  public Set<Car> getPremiumCars(String filter) throws Exception {
    return getPremiumVehicle(this::getCars, filter);
  }

  public Set<Bike> getPremiumBikes(String filter) throws Exception {
    return getPremiumVehicle(this::getBikes, filter);
  }

  public Callable<Set<Car>> getCars(String feature) {
    return getVehicle(this::getCarsWithFeature, feature);
  }

  public Callable<Set<Bike>> getBikes(String feature) {
    return getVehicle(this::getBikesWithFeature, feature);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a base class of Car and Bike, then put the common method there.
Then extend the Car and Bike from it. Update the common method using the base class. Sample hints for the implementation is given below:

```
class Vehicle {
  public Set<Vehicle> getWithFilter(String filter) {
    final Callable<Set<Vehicle>> retryGet = new RetryingCallable<>(retryStrategy(), get(filter));
    return retryGet.call();            
  }
  public Callable<Set<Vehicle>> getWithFeature(String feature) {
    return new Callable<Set<Vehicle>>() {
        public Set<Vehicle> call() throws Exception {
            Set<Vehicle> vehicles = getWithFeature(feature); 
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(vehicles);
        }
    };
  }

} 
class Car extends Vehicle {
}
class Bike extends Vehicle {
}
```

Now to call use:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.getWithFilter(/* Pass parameter*/);

Bike bike = new Bike();
bike.getWithFilter(/* Pass parameter*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned in the comments above by @Piro there are 2 different calls `getCarsWithFeature` and `getBikesWithFeature`. Even with a base class that part of code will still have to be there. What part do you think I can move to the base class?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try. But, what if instead of Car and Bike I had totally unrelated Classes? I cannot have a base class in that case. What would be the recommendation in that case?

Comment: In that case, you have to use generic template or use Java Object class, then cast to appropriate class.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well. So my question talks about Generics. I cannot use the Base class approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165506/discussion-between-maddie-and-i-ahmed).